# Bijection between $3^{\mathbb N}$ and $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals, multisets

Since $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ is the set of all subsets of $\mathbb N$,

For each element $a \in \mathbb N$ and every subset $S\subset N$, we can define a function $f$:

$f(a) = 0$ if $a \notin S$

$f(a) = 1$ if $a \in S$

This proves a bijection between $2^{\mathbb N}$ and $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ exists and therefore, $|2^{\mathbb N}| = \mathcal P(\mathbb N)$.

Is there a bijection between $|3^{\mathbb N}|$ and $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$?

Every infinite ternary sequence would need to correspond with one and only one subset $S \subset N$.

An approach similar to a powerset operation is as follows:

$f(a) = 0$ if $a \notin S$

$f(a) = 1$ if $a \in S \oplus a+1 \in S$

$f(a) = 2$ if $a \in S$ ^ $a+1 \in S$ (^ denotes AND operator)

It is fairly easy to see that this function is a bijection for all ternary sequences with only $0$ or $2$, since we know exactly what elements will be a member of $S$ and which ones won't (i.e. if $a$ is a member, so is $a+1$, and if $a$ isn't a member, then neither is $a+1$).

The only problem is when $f(a)=1$. We know that either $a$ or $a+1$ will be in the subset, but not both, so there are exactly two subsets for each $1$ in the sequence. Being an infinite ternary sequences, infinitely many $1$'s may occur, thus we may end up with an uncountable number of subsets for a single ternary sequence.

This approach also fails for finite sets instead of $\mathbb N$.

A more general set theoretical approach towards even defining $3^A$ is as follows, but it doesn't provide a solution to my initial question:

If we have two sets, $A$ and $B$, with $|A| = |B|$ and $A \cap B = {\emptyset}$ ($A$ and $B$ are disjoint to avoid multiset theory), then we can define a non communitive binary operation $ϛ$ as follows

$A ψ B = C$

$C$ is the set of all subsets $S$ with the following properties:

For every element $a \in S$:

$a \in A$

or

If $a \in B$, then some corresponding (via a bijection) $a' \in A$.

From this definition, it is clear that for any $T \subset B$, $T \not\subset C$, thus the order of $A$ and $B$ matters.

Therefore, $C = 3^A$.

This can clearly be seen with finite sets for example:

$A = $ {$0,1$}

$B = $ {$2,3$}

Assume a bijection $a\in A$:

$f(a) = a+2$, $a+2 \in B$.

$C = $ {{},{$0$},{$1$},{$0,1$},{$0,2$},{$1,3$},{$0,1,2$},{$0,1,3$},{$0,1,2,3$}}

The following example could be instead written using multisets, with $2$ being a repetition of $0$, and $3$ being a repetition of $1$, but by definition, sets cannot contain multiple elements, so the need for a disjoint set with same cardinality is necessary.

At the very least, is possible to define $|3^{A}|$ using a non-communative binary operation for sets $A$ and $B$, but can this be done for unary operations on $A$ (which is necessary to define a bijection between $3^\mathbb{N}$ and the powerset $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb N)$? Any thoughts?

Comment: The easiest way to prove that there's a bijection between $3^\mathbb{N}$ and $2^\mathbb{N}$ is via [Cantor-Bernstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem): there is an obvious injection $2^\mathbb{N}\rightarrow3^\mathbb{N}$, and in the other direction we can just compose the obvious injection $3^\mathbb{N}\rightarrow 4^\mathbb{N}$ with the injection (indeed, bijection) $4^\mathbb{N}\rightarrow 2^\mathbb{N}$ gotten by thinking about the map $0\mapsto 00, 1\mapsto 01, 2\mapsto 10, 3\mapsto 11$. Note that CB is fully explicit and does not use the axiom of choice.

Comment: In fact, you can do even better: it's not hard to show that there is a bijection between $2^\mathbb{N}$ and $(2^\mathbb{N})^\mathbb{N}$ (think about [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) and [pairing functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function)), and CB then turns this into a useful "nuke."

Comment: Yes, it is easy to prove a bijection exists. But if you want to find a particular bijection, writing one out, that is harder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All answers are overkill IMO. Its easy to define a bijection between $2^\mathbb{N} $ and $3^\mathbb{N}$ which then answers your question;for this map $0-1,1-01,2-00$ so for instance $0121..$ gets mapped to $1010001...$  its easy to see this is a bijection.

Comment: It is not too difficult, but It would be nice to show how this extends to a bijection between $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $k^{\mathbb{N}}$ for any $k\ge3$.

Comment: If you switch the role of $0$ and $1$, this becomes the identity when mapping $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ to itself.

Comment: I like this bijection although it more generally relies on an underlying set being countable (in this case $\mathbb N$).

Answer (score 1):

$2^{\mathbb{N}}$ is in a bijective correspondence with the real numbers between $0$ and $1$ (think of their binary representation). Similarly, $3^{\mathbb{N}}$ is in a bijective correspondence with the same interval of real numbers (ternary representation). Therefore, they have the same cardinality, that of the Continuum.

Comment: Unfortunately, those correspondence are not bijective because of the non-uniqueness of the binary and ternary representations.

Comment: @jjagmath Yeah, but that problem can be solved easily.Still this is nuking the problem.